# WordPress carousel links only clickable on mobile

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress-theming, wordpress-shortcode

Website https://mearesmarine.com

I believe the issue started with a recent update to WP 6.1. Please view the "Recently Listed" section. On desktop, the links are there but not clickable. On mobile this works as expected.

I have tried.

Updating vc_carousel javascript files.
Custom CSS / assumed maybe a position/z-index problem.
Updating plugins/theme.

Comment: I think all the 6 images/cards are showing so that is why there is no action taken by links. If that is the case then it is expected behaviour. Try adding some more cards and see if links are clickable.

Comment: Or if there is a setting for loop. You can try turning that on.

Comment: Consider marking your touch and wheel event listeners as `passive` to improve your page's scroll performance. (Would this be related?)

Comment: Still cannot figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

The solution ended up being to update a plugin bxslider which was a javascript file loaded by the theme.